# How to import one android.mk mdule into another android.mk module in Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

In Android in the Application i want to import one android.mk file into another Android.mk file in the Application

for this i have used in one Andorid.mk file which is to be imported into another module of same project

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := EDSDKModule
LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=libEDSDK.a
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
TARGET_PLATFORM:=android-8
TARGET_ARCH_ABI:=armeabi
TARGET_ABI:=$(TARGET_PLATFORM)-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

and main Andorid.mk file is written is

```
include C:\my_module\Android.mk
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := EDSK
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := foo 
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample.c
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := EDSDKModule
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
TARGET_PLATFORM:=android-8
TARGET_ARCH_ABI:=armeabi
TARGET_ABI:=$(TARGET_PLATFORM)-$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
$(call import-module,EDSDKModule)
```

but i have got this error on building project using Android-NDk i.e

please suggest some solutions on how to import one module into another module of android.mk file in a project

Comment: have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355055/android-ndk-import-module-code-reuse

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem is here :

```
    $NDK_MODULE_PATH\C:\Final FOlder\final c\Mysetup\newworks\SimpleApp\jni\path1\Android.mk:
    /*here i have given directory path of android.mk file */
```

Possible mistakes :

- Try to get rid of the empty spaces in the path :

  ```
  C:\Final FOlder\final c\
  ```

to something like this :

```
    C:\FInal_Folder\final_c\myotherdir\xyz.mk
```

- If you are using a absolute path like :

  ```
  C:\mypath\myotherdir\xyz.mk
  ```

then you **NEED NOT** prefix it with **`$NDK_MODULE_PATH`**. Just use the above absolute path itself, which is **`C:\mypath\myotherdir\xyz.mk`**

- You need an **`include`** keyword infront of your above include statement :

  ```
  # comment : including my mk file here
  include C:\mypath\myotherdir\xyz.mk
  ```
- Get rid of the **`:`** in the end of your include statement

So you have to do something like :

```
    include C:\mypath\myotherdir\xyz.mk
```

**OR**

If you have the mk file in **NDK LOCAL FOLDER** then

```
    include $NDK_MODULE_PATH\mylocaldir\xyz.mk
```

Hope this helps. CHeers!

Comment: i have used following commends in Android.mk file **** include C:\my_module\Android.mk LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir) include $(CLEAR_VARS) LOCAL_MODULE := EDSK LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := foo LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sample.c LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libEDSDK.a include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY) $(call import-module,EDSDKModule) 
************but i get error i.e *Android NDK: C:\my_module\Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'EDSDKModule' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
jni/Android.mk:14: Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
Android NDK:

Comment: Can you tell me, from where you copied the original **"C:\my_module\Android.mk"** file from?

Because your imported Android.mk seems to be looking for the following modules : **`libEDSDK.a, EDSDK, EDSDKErrors, EDSDKTypes`** from **`$(LOCAL_PATH)`**.

I suggest you **COPY EVERYTHING** from the **original directory containing** the imported **`Android.mk`** and the **`libEDSDK.a`**, into the local main Android.mk directory.

That should solve the problem. Cheers!

Comment: in my_module folder i have placed Android.mk,EDSDk.h,EDSDkERRors.h EDSDKTypes.h and libEDSDl.a file from the project and in jni folder of the project i have also placed EDSDk.h,EDSDkERRors.h EDSDKTypes.h and libEDSDl.a file but problem is still the same can explain more  about NDK LOCAL FOLDER sorry but i don't understand it ow i placed imported Android.mk in  NDK LOCAL FOLDER i can't understand this  "NDK LOCAL FOLDER"

Comment: Can you update the new ANdroid.mk in your question please? Add a section below existing content, so that I can take a look at the whole Android.mk file.